# Detect UITabBar Selected Index/ Item Changes that is set Programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I would like to know how do we detect when the selected TabBar Item or Index is changed ***when* *the changes is done programmatically***?

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

This two delegate function only detect changes when the tabBar Item was selected by user. It does not fire when the changes to the selectedIndex was done programmatically.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    println("tabBarController didSelectViewController")
}

override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    println("tabBar didSelectItem")
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Previous answers are sufficient to "detect" the changes, however it does  not detect which index is being pressed.

```
func selectItemWithIndex(value: Int) {
    self.tabBarControllertabBarController.selectedIndex = value;
    self.tabBar(self.tabBar, didSelectItem: (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[value]);
}
```

**self.selectedIndex** will not return the selected index right away. To check which item is being pressed, we would need to compare the item with the tabBarItems in our *UITabBarController*

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[0]{ 
       //Do something if index is 0
    }
    else if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[1]{
       //Do something if index is 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that calling directly a delegate method is a good practice because its purpose is to be fired automatically.

Answer (score 29):

Along all answers here, if you subclassed `UITabBarController` already, here's a simple solution for all tab bar changes (User initiated and programmatic ):

```
// Override selectedViewController for User initiated changes
override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? {
    didSet {
        tabChangedTo(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)
    }
}
// Override selectedIndex for Programmatic changes    
override var selectedIndex: Int {
    didSet {
        tabChangedTo(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)
    }
}

// handle new selection
 func tabChangedTo(selectedIndex: Int) {}
```

Comment: Man! You saved my job! Thank you so much! It has solved my biggest problems of showing initial vc for every tab :)

Comment: Thank god for this answer, was actually starting to send me a little crazy

Answer (score 5):

In swift, you can do it by overriding `selectedIndex` property of `UITabBarController`.

First subclass `UITabBarController` and add all the following code.

```
//Overriding this to get callback whenever its value is changes
   override var selectedIndex: Int {
      didSet {
         handleTabSelection(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)
      }
   }
```

Also add this delegate method of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    //Tab tapped
    guard let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers else { return }
    let tappedIndex = viewControllers.index(of: viewController)! 
    //Tab tapped at tappedIndex
    handleTabSelection(selectedIndex: tappedIndex)
}
```

Finally, we call this method from both places so that all the cases are handled.

```
private func handleTabSelection(selectedIndex: Int) {
    //Do something on tab selection at selectedIndex
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

Here's a somewhat safer Swift-3 version, of what's been proposed above:

```
func selectItem(withIndex index: Int) {

    if  let controller = tabBarController,
        let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar,
        let items = tabBarController?.tabBar.items
    {
        guard index < items.count else { return }

        controller.selectedIndex = index
        controller.tabBar(tabBar, didSelect: items[index])
    }
}
```

UITabBarController:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if let items = tabBar.items {
        items.enumerated().forEach { if $1 == item { print("your index is: \($0)") } }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
selectItem(withIndex: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

that can't be done but some kind of hacking it can be done and i am sure that's gonna be a temporary solution for this problem.
override below method for tabbarcontrollerdelegate do your stuff inside this is called when tab is switched in either way programatically or tapping on tab bar item.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    toVC.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontFuturaMedium11, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.colorAppThemeColor], for: .normal)
    fromVC.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontFuturaBTBook11, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.colorStudentTabText], for: .normal)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a lovely solution to this. Thanks to Ckouta for the idea.

I simply create a function to change the index and fire the delegate protocol of UITabBar's didSelectItem

```
func selectItemWithIndex(value: Int) {
    self.tabBarControllertabBarController.selectedIndex = value;
    self.tabBar(self.tabBar, didSelectItem: (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[value]);
}
```

Usage

```
    selectItemWithIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I only cared about the selectedIndex in one of the VCs in the tab bar controller stack. So I KVO:ed segmentedIndex on the tabbarcontroller instance from that VC. Works well, no real problems.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4:-** You have to use these lines of code for detecting `UITabBar` selected item index.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    if item == (tabBar.items)![0] {
        // do something with 1st tab
    }
    else if item == (tabBar.items)![1] {
        // do something with 2nd tab
    }
}
```