# Trying to understand TabBarDelegate

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uitabbar

In one of my ViewControllers I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController ;
    [tabBarController setDelegate:self];
}
```

and :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController*)viewController {
    NSLog(@"Yup!");
}
```

Whenever I switch tabs in my multi-tab setup, the console spits out

> Yup

just as expected.

However, when I add

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
tabController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

to my AppDelegate.m's

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

the 'Yup' doesn't show anymore.

How come?

Answer (score 0):

didSelectViewController will call when you select/change tabs from the app itself, it will not call when you set the selectedIndex programmatically

`tabController.selectedIndex = 1;` , will mostly useful when you want to set default tab or want to change the selectedIndex programmatically

From [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:didSelectViewController:):
    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
     didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

> it is called only in response to user taps in the tab bar and is not
>   called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically.

You can try calling that method manually like this:

```
- (void) selectedItemWithIndex:(int)value {
    tabbar.selectedIndex = value;
    [self tabBarController:tabbar didSelectViewController:tabbar.viewControllers.firstObject];//place you vc here by array or manually
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30700712/4557505

Comment: That makes sense, but I would expect that the 'Yup' would nevertheless kick in when I change tabs

Comment: I still don't see a reason why a method in the AppDelegate will cancel other functionality. And I am too old to do Swift.

Comment: where did it cancel the functionality it is not implemented like this as I quoted from the apple doc, you are just setting a property