# Run a function after selecting a tab bar controller scene

Tags: swift

I have a tab bar controller with two scenes:
1 scene) Loads pictures at the click of a button.
2 scene) Must upload pictures when this scene is selected.

How to make the search function immediately execute when switching to the second scene?
Both scenes have one controller.

[image]

Comment: Hint: `viewDidAppear`

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692206/detect-uitabbar-selected-index-item-changes-that-is-set-programmatically